# How to drop folder to get files

Tags: javascript

I want make a feature like Google drive or other storages. Drop files or folders and upload them. there is my code:

```
function onDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.dataTransfer.items);

    var formData = new formData();
    for (var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.files; i++) {
        formData.append('uploads[]', e.dataTransfer.files[i]);
    }
    //send formData to api
}
```

So far so good, it upload files well, however, folders doesn't work.
I think the solution is getting all files under the folder, and expect will find the directory path information in e.dataTransfer. Unfortunately, I don't get folder data.

It's it possible or should find other way?

Comment: iirc, you have to use the entries collection instead of the files. it's different and takes almost all new code. iirc...

Comment: See Dropzone.js